Rsync Compare-Dest Not Recognizing Wildcard
I am trying to use rysnc to do multi level incremental backup, however I am running into some issues. It seems as though rsync does not recognize wild cards in compare-dest. I run the following code
rsync -av /home/j/test/source/ --compare-dest=/home/j/test/destination/*/ /home/j/test/destination/00/

It will give me the following message.
--compare-dest arg does not exist: /home/j/test/destination/*

I run into this issue even after trying to run the code again and place my backup in a new directory
rsync -av /home/j/test/source/ --compare-dest=/home/j/test/destination/*/ /home/j/test/destination/01/

On the second attempt it will copy everything from the source folder to destination/01/ instead of looking for changes in all the directories within the destination directory as we would expect with a wildcard.
The intent is to be able to continually make new directories withing the destination directory to these new directories perform incremental backup of the source while comparing all previous backups.
Not sure how to get wildcards to work with --compare-dest, I have seen other people use them with rsync to do a very similar thing.
I am running Ubuntu on WSL2 and have tried the same on my server running Ubuntu 22.04. Some guidance on this would be much appreciated.
Thanks,
J
